# How to design the Unity Container?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have three projects: *WebAPI*, *Services* and *Repository*.

`WebAPI` has a reference to `Services` and `Services` has reference to `Repository`.

Now I need to add a Unity Container for `Services` and `Repositories` but in `WebAPI` it's doesn't allow to add a reference to `Repository`, `WebAPI` has reference just for `Services`.

I know how to configure the `unity` for `Services`, but how to this also for `Repository`

How can I change this in order to obtain the desired design ?

Comment: Why can't you add a reference to Repositories?  Perhaps you could have a method in `Services` which accepts a Unity Container and *that* method could register the Dependencies in `Repository`?  Downside here is that `Services` then needs to have Unity References which I guess you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @GPW,  Because the `controller` has nothing to do with `repositories`. Data arrives in `repository` through `services`

Comment: So just architectural decision then?  Fair enough.  The approach I take to these things is broadly as I suggest above - Each project has a method in which it registers its dependencies.    a similar alternative could be an entirely separate "Infrastructure" project which has references to every project which has dependencies to register, and this has the responsibility for registering everything with IoC for all projects (and is invoked only by the WebApi project on Startup).

Comment: @GPW, yes, I like your last idea. Please post it as an answer in order to vote it.

Comment: I've done so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to simply add another project - name it something like "Infrastructure". This project can then have sole responsibility for registering things with IoC - so this project would need to reference every project which contains anything that needs registering, and it could be invoked by the WebAPI project.

This way the WebApi project doesn't need to directly know about anything in the Respository; it only knows how to get an IoC container which can then be used by everything.